# Pass dynamic values to SCSS File inAngular 6

Tags: angular, sass

I'm using SCSS in my code for styling and now I have a scenario where I have to pass dynamic values to SCSS file

`$primary-colors: (
    50 : #e8f5f6,
    300 : #77c2cb,
    500 : #5ab5c0,`

`$primary-selected-color: darken( map-get($primary-colors, 500), 8% );`

Instead of the fixed colors need to set dynamic colrs.So I have done something like this

`$primary-colors: (
    50 : var(--color1),
    300 : var(--color1),
    500 : var(--color1),`

and changing the attribute value based on color picked but When I wrote something like this there is an compile time error here
`$primary-selected-color: darken( map-get($primary-colors, 500), 8% );` stating 
[image]
How Can I solve this or Is there any effective way to achieve this by passing the values dynamically from typescript file

Answer (score 1):

SCSS compiles into CSS. It cant be dynamicly changed by events or actions using your component because its just css at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that returns your `$primary-colors` map with a color you pass in from your .scss files.

```
@function get-map($color) {
    @return (
        50: $color
        300: $color,
        500: $color
    )
}
```

Is that what you’re looking for?

The only other way to change styles through JS/TS is by adding classes/attributes or css in js